# Error on prepare statement in php custom class mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

please bear me im new with `OOP` and `mysqli` here is my php custom class for database connection

```
class mysqldbconnect {
        protected $mysqli;
        public function __constructor() {
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','todo');
        }
        public function select_query() {
            $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM dos");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id,$task,$sday,$lday,$des);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $count = $stmt->num_rows();
            if ( $count > 0 )
            {
                while ( $stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo $task." ".$sday." ".$lday." ".$des;
                }
            } else {
                echo "Nothing to do :) its great..";
            }
        }
    }
```

and on this line

```
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM dos");
```

i getting following error

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

i tried `var_dump` function in `select_query`function to check `$this-.mysqli` and its returning NULL so error is obviously right now i can't figure how to remove this error ?.
please help me and i know its stupid question.

Comment: What is your code to call `select_query`?

Comment: $db = new mysqldbconnect();
$db->select_query();
@Perry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem I see with that chunk of code is that you don't have a constructor.

It should be `public function __construct() {` **not** `__constructor`

That said, you should do some error checking to make sure the mysqli object was created successfully.

Comment: Very common around here, and always difficult to spot, and difficult to debug.

Comment: Agreed. Always good to have another pair of eyes look at it :)

Comment: Another one is when an OP has `__contruct` --- That one always takes me a minute to catch on.

Comment: thanks sir @mituw16 it was greatest mistake of mine now everthing working :)

Comment: for others after correcting __constructor to __construct now everything is working perfectly